# How would i write a program in python that connects to a DGT chess board and prints the moves being made in real time?

Tags: python, pyserial, chess

I am trying to write a program in python that connects to a DGT chess board and recieves the data and prints the moves in real time as they are being made (example: ng1f3). Ive tried asking chat gpt but as usual it has been no help. Ive also looked online for similar projects but found nothing like what i am trying to do.

ive tried getting the data using the serial library. the port and the baudrate are both correct. the board sends 8 bytes of data for each move. this code runs but does not print anything when i move the pieces on the board. ive even tried contacting the manufacturer to see if the boards have any sort of protection against this but they said they couldnt help me with this and instead just sent me the document with the description of the comunication protocol (one drive link to file: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqF5qQ2nPQ81nkBZqQAMfY93mfdJ?e=eia1mO). i am also fairly new to python and this website.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600)

while True:
    data = ser.read(8)
    print(data)
```

***edit:*** I have since tried:

```py
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, timeout=2) 
ser.write(bytes([0x45])) # message to request serial number 
test = ser.read(20) 
output = test.decode('ascii', errors='replace') # convert bytes to string print(output)
```

A response was received, but it wasn't quite as expected.

Comment: Please, instead of [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75436347/5459839) your question and reposting with more detail, **update** your (original) question.

Comment: Did you try searching for DGT on PyPI?

Comment: @buran i found a library called asyncdgt but it has not been updated since its release in 2015 and just throws up errors. i thought it would be easier this way since i only need to recieve the string of the move being made as ive already made a program that will make use of it.

Comment: Please add more information about the communication protocol.

Comment: @MisplacedSoutherner i have added a one drive link to the file since i cant upload the file directly

Comment: @MarkoStojanović Thanks. If you're connected just using a USB cable, you won't be able to use pyserial. Is there maybe another connector or pins on the board, that says RS-232 or serial?

Comment: @MisplacedSoutherner there is a female RS-232 connector that i have connected to a USB adapter that goes in to my computer

Comment: Ok, I am assuming you mean you have an RS-232 to USB adapter?

Comment: yes i do have an adapter

Comment: "Ive tried asking chat gpt but as usual it has been no help."  Comment like this this doesn't help anyone... this comment look as chitchat and should be removed. When sharing your search and research efforts please focus on trusted sources, be specific about what you found and why it didn't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel confident that everything is connected properly, try doing this:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, timeout=2)
ser.write(bytes([0x45])) # I think this is the message to request serial number.
test = ser.read(20)  # Not sure how many bytes are returned

print(test) # this prints a byte string
print(test.hex()) # this prints the byte string as a string of hex w/out the "0x/"  characters
print("The Message ID is " +  str(test[0:1]))  # You sent a'0x45' command you get back a'0x91' reply
print("The length of the message is " + str(test[1:3])) 
print("The Serial number is " + str(test[3:8]))
```

Does that print anything at all?

***edit:*** Changed the serial write to a byte type.

***edit 2:*** It looks like the board might write something upon start up. Another thing to try is:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, timeout=5)  # timeout long enough to turn on board
test = ser.read(1000) # excess amount to read, but we don't want to miss anything
print(test)
```

***edit 3:*** Now that we have verified communications with the board, we can start experimenting with trying to write a script that will read the movement of the chess pieces. Let's try this:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, timeout=2)
DTG_REQ_UPDATE_BOARD = bytes([0x44])

while 1:
    timeout = 0
    ser.write(DTG_REQ_UPDATE_BOARD)
    while timeout < 10:
        movement = ser.read(20)  
        
        if movement != 0:
            print(movement)
            timeout = 10
        else:
            timeout += 1
            continue
```

1. Turn on your board.
2. Start the above script.
3. Start moving pieces like you would if you were playing a game.
4. Look for things to start printing out in your console/terminal.

It's a quick and dirty way of looping (it's an infinite loop and you will have to force stop the process when you are done running your script), but it should do the job for testing purposes.

Comment: the program prints out:
b''

Comment: Ok, I would really check that everything is wired correctly, and you have a proper adapter. Does your adapter sort of look like this: https://a.co/d/4stmpVK ?
Also, I would take note of *15.1* of your document, because moving pieces on your board will not do anything until you tell the board to do so. Definitely stick with sending a simple, single byte command like the one asking for serial number at first until you get a reply back from the board.

Comment: everything is wired correctly. i think this is the adapter that came with the board and it has a LED that flashes when it is first connected and when i run my code

Comment: Those are good signs. The LEDs seem to indicate you are at least transmitting to the chess board. Usually that would lead me to believe there is a problem with what you're transmitting, however as far as I can tell in *9.1* sending ```0x45``` should work. It might be worth double checking with the manufacturer again, and tell them that you have verified that you are transmitting to the board, but when you send ```0x45``` you receive nothing at all in reply.

Comment: i had an idea to convert the recieved bytes to string and also change the code to request the serial number:
' import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600, timeout=2)
ser.write(bytes([0x45]))  # message to request serial number

test = ser.read(20)
output = test.decode('ascii', errors='replace')  # convert bytes to string
print(output) '


the program now prints the serial number with an unknown character at the start: �13663. but 13663 is infact the correct serial number

Comment: See my edit above^ I was mistaken in telling you to input a hex number by itself. You're  going in the right direction. Can you tell me what the output of the edited code block above returns? It should be a byte string ```b'247987example24883'``` The unknown character is confusing on it's own.

**also, please take your comment, wrap it in a code block, and add it as an edit to your original post. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: the edited code return the same thing as before: b' '

Comment: *sigh...that's on me for trying to get clever. I made another edit. This time, we use your write function, but we use the read function from previous edit. Now you should (hopefully) get a byte string back.

Comment: I also added ```print(hex(test))```. That way even if you see something weird in the byte string, we can get the raw hex of what is read printed out.

Comment: the ` print(hex(test)) ` throws up an error. TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
b''

Comment: @MarkoStojanović Wow, I'm really just striking out left and right. I got my functions mixed up, you want ```print(test.hex())```

Comment: now the program prints: b' ' None

Comment: Something seems off here. If you compare what you did that works, and what I am suggesting, my ```test``` should equal your ```test```. I really hate to ask this question, but is the chessboard powered on when you are running your code?

Comment: my bad i didnt realise the board was unplugged as the LED still flashed. this is the output now: b'\x91\x00\x0813663' 9100083133363633 None

Comment: Ok that looks right. Look at **15.8** in your manual and then ```print(len(test))```. You should see they are both 8 bytes. The first 4 is a header (which includes the response ID of 0x91), and the last 4 represent the serial number.

Comment: the '0x91' command on 15.8 again doesnt print anything and shows a length of 0.

Comment: See the new edit above. **15.8** describes how to parse the response from the board, it isn't a command. 0x91 is a 'board to computer' ID, 0x45 is a 'computer to board' ID.

Comment: this is the result from the edited code: b'\x91\x00\x0813663'
9100083133363633
The Message ID is b'\x91'
The length of the message is b'\x00\x08'
The Serial number is b'13663'

Comment: Exactly! This is what you are supposed to receive. I added yet another edit. The edit includes a new block that should allow you to read the movement of pieces on the board.

Comment: great the moves are being picked up and printed in real time. the program appears to print twice for every move. once for when the piece i picked up and again when it is placed down: b'\x8e\x00\x059\x00'
b''
b''
b'\x8e\x00\x05*\x03'. i tried the previous method of converting the bytes to string but it didnt work. this is what it converts to: � *. ive also added a timeout because it appears that when you slide the piece across it registers every square as a move.

Comment: You'll have to keep expirementing with your code, referencing the manual,  and googling different methods of parsing your data. You're off to a good start. Since your new here, if you ask a question on here and you feel like someone has answered it well, you can mark their answer as correct. It helps others who are having the same issues you had, find the answers they need.

Comment: ive marked it as correct but it wouldnt let me upvote. i will keep working on parsing the data and working on making use of it. thank you for your help